# How to add containers to same network in Docker

Tags: docker

I'm running containers with the `docker run` command and would like to add them to the same network such that each container is able to connect to each other using the container name.

I tried the following command: `docker run --network=bridge` (default docker network), but the containers couldn't connect to each other with their names.

How can I make it work?

Comment: Have you looked into docker-compose? This makes managing sets of containers much easier.

Answer (score 56):

First, define your user-defined bridge network:

```
docker network create your-network-name
```

Then, connect your containers to the network that you just created:

```
docker network connect your-network-name container-name
```

Or connect with the run command:

```
docker run --network=your-network-name your-image
```

Now, containers in the same network `your-network-name` can talk to each others via container name.

Comment: why doesn't the default bridged network allow to do this?

Comment: @TuomasToivonen `default bridged network` you also can do that by ` --link` option. `user-defined` is more convenient, but `docker-compose` is the best choice... See more here https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge

Answer (score 13):

You can attach a network to an existing container using this docker command:

```
docker network connect network-name container-name
```

Then, you can inspect using the network interface that you create that container was successfully connected or not.

```
docker inspect network-name
```

Answer (score 1):

I will add to the above answers why you cannot connect conainters in `network bridge` with their names

According to the documentation https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/

> Containers on the default bridge network can only access each other by
> IP addresses, unless you use the --link option, which is considered
> legacy. On a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve each other by name or alias.